# Числительное с прилагательным в "Дневнике писателя"

Tags: падежи, числительные, определения

[Преступник и намеревающийся совершить преступление — это два разные лица, но одной категории. Что же, если, приготовляясь к преступлению сознательно, преступник скажет себе: «Нет преступления!» Что, назовет его народ «несчастным»?](http://rulibrary.ru/dostoevskiy/dnevnik_pisatelya/10)

"Два разные лица" - правильно ли употреблено Федором Михайловичем (или редактором) числительное с прилагательным?

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что для XIX века такое согласование было нормой.
В словаре Даля (1863—1866) в статье [**разный**](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9):
*Это **два разные дела**, не путай их вместе.*

Если посмотреть в Нацкорпусе, то станет понятно, что ТАК говорили вплоть до первой четверти двадцатого века (["два разные"](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&startyear=1800&text=lexform&req=%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5&api=1.0&mode=main&env=alpha&endyear=2019&nodia=1&p=0)).

Л. Н. Толстой:
это были два разные врага; это два разные дьявола; два разные слова.

А. М. Федоров: два разные чувства.
В. А. Гиляровский:  два разные понятия.
М. М. Пришвин:  два разные мира.
Н. С. Лесков:  два разные восклика.
И. А. Гончаров: два разные голоса.

Говорить **об ошибке** никак нельзя — так было правильно в **то** время.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, данная форма является грубой ошибкой согласования числительного с прилагательным. Простое правило:

**Если определяемое (главное) слово имеет мужской либо средний род, окончанием прилагательных будет -ых либо -их. Если же род женский, окончанием будет -ые либо -ие.**

Более того, существительное может находиться в форме множественного числа, причём прилагательное будет находиться до числительного либо после всего сочетания, где оно приобретает только окончание -ие.

Это же правило относится и к причастиям.

Comment: Вы позволите задать Вам вопросы (просто мне интересно Ваше мнение). 1) Скажите, пожалуйста, почему Достоевский использовал такое согласование, неужели он был неграмотным человеком? Можно ли  предположить, что в его время такое написание допускалось? Тогда это надо указать в ответе. 2) Как Вы думаете, как можно объяснить это правило?  Допускает ли оно варианты? 3) Две узких полосы  - это неправильно? Спасибо.

Comment: Начнем по порядку. Если изучить пунктуацию русских авторов-классиков (в некоторых случаях дело ей не ограничивается), то можно и не такое найти. Тот же самый Гоголь, что мне запомнилось наиболее чётко, не раз не употреблял нормативные для **современных правил** знаки препинания. Здесь я отметил сочетание "современные правила". Вот точно так же правила, если таковые имелись, могли быть совершенно другими во время того же самого Достоевского. В моем старом учебнике данное правило трактовалось примерно так же, причем не было никаких исключений. Если рассуждать по данному, правилу, то неправильно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне просто показалось, что выражение "грубая ошибка" не очень подходит к данной ситуации. Кроме того, в этой теме возможны варианты и влияние различных факторов на выбор падежа. В частности: "Если формы И.п. мн. числа сущ. ж. рода отличаются по ударению от формы Р.п ед. числа (ср.: го́ры — горы́, слёзы — слезы́), то определение обычно ставится в Р.п. мн. числа: ДВЕ ВЫСОКИХ ГОРЫ, две крупных слезы. http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-193-opredelenie-pri-sushchestvitelnom-zavisyashchem-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre

Comment: Да, я ещё при составления ответа заметил, что это сочетание как-то неуместно. А вот со вторым примером я как-то не сталкивался.

Comment: Весь смысл подобных правил - это обеспечить по возможности привычную сочетаемость рядом стоящих слов. Корректный падеж для всех родов - это Р.п. , но для ж. рода делается исключение с учетом ударения.  Маленькие дЕвочки - две маленькие дЕвочки, такое сочетание кажется корректным,  оно и употребляется.  Кстати, по ссылке дан хороший источник, я его не сразу нашла.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Пожалуйста. И желаю Вам успехов в работе на форуме.