# Раньше так было правильно и для мужского рода?

Tags: склонение, прилагательные, род

Владимир Короленко (1853 — 1921)
Старый звонарь (Весенняя идиллия)

*А два **самые маленькие** дисканта, точно торопясь, чтобы не отстать, вплетались между больших и радостно, точно малые ребята, пели вперегонку: «Христос воскресе!»*

Comment: "Таковы были два самые усердные посетителя Обломова."/"Это были два самые известные доктора."  писали так, иногда...

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClUqLAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKKy4qL/zn4MFMglncmNyZWF0ZWRABWoEMC45NXgAMgIIAToBAUIeChwKGgoDcmVxEhMKEdC00LLQsCDRgdCw0LzRi9C1MAE=

Comment: жили два самые образованные народа - жили два народа. А не жили двое народов. Самых для согласования должно оканчиваться на -ов, -ых, -их. То есть доктор - доктора, это множественное число от доктор или притяжательный падеж чей - доктора? "Таковы были два самые усердные", то есть тут проблема не в "самые маленькие", а в дисканта - почему такая форма, а не дисканты. Два баса пели. Дисканта - не именительный падеж. Два - пели, самые маленькие согласовано с два, и дисканта согласовано с два, Два - подлежащие, остальное дополнения и прочее.

Comment: Собаки Павлова, собаки самые маленькие Павлова пели вперегонку. Возможно, если реверснуть: самые маленькие собаки Павлова пели вперегонку, - то проблемы не будет. А самые маленькие два баса пели. Так что проблема в расположении определения относительно определяемого слова и в том что дисканта - это не множественное от дисканты.

Comment: Касательно же "самых лучших", проблема в том, эта конструкция употреблялась, если "самых лучших(из) докторов. То есть это не доктора, а из докторов, разница в этом, докторов - также является дополнением. То есть было две конструкции и двое самых маленьких дискантов - звучит также криво, так что делать? То есть если сам+ых то нужно окончание -ов(или другое подобное), а если самые тогда окончание -а. "до городовых самых валов" "вода поднимается до самых берегов"(17 в). "что и самых обманщиков не сомневались принимать за чаемого ими мессию".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вместо вступления**

Мы занимаемся текстологией, об этом вопрос? **Текстология** — филологическая отрасль, изучающая и восстанавливающая историю и судьбу произведений письменности и литературы с целью дальнейшего исследования, интерпретации…  Серьезная наука, причем для очень внимательных людей. Ею действительно надо заниматься  основательно и неспешно. Поэтому я смотрю лишь **на выводы**, а то еще получится: слона-то я и не заметил.

**Вот вывод**: «Да, именно так обычно писали до первой трети двадцатого века». Серьёзное и ответственное  суждение…  Но вот еще в текстах второй половины 19 века у известных писателей я встречаю **примеры с Р.п.**, и они мне  гораздо ближе. **Почему же закрепился Р.п.?** Неужели большевики во всем виноваты — и здесь революцию устроили?

И этот вечный вопрос **о правильности** в черно-белом мире: Это правильно? — Да-да, именно так правильно. Обычное наше суждение и деления всего на правильное и неправильное. А мир правильности — **не черно-белый**, а цветной, меняющийся. Эти перемены возникают, постепенно накапливаются — и вдруг происходит революция! **Победило то**, что казалось неверным, вот ведь незадача!

Чтобы понять это, надо перейти от текстологии к **грамматике и правилам** письма.

**Ответ**

**[Правило Розенталя](https://evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)** (цитирую полностью)

**§193.** Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре

1. При существительных **мужского и среднего рода**, зависящих от числительных **два, три, четыре** (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме **родительного падежа множественного числа**: два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола. Например: ...Офицеры ели жадно, без разговоров, наверстывали за два потерянных в боях дня (Шолохов); Два крайних окна в первом этаже закрыты изнутри газетными листами... (А.Н. Толстой).
2. При существительных **женского рода** в указанных условиях определение чаще ставится **в форме именительного падежа** (или совпадающего с ним винительного при неодушевленных существительных) множественного числа. Например: две большие комнаты выходили окнами в сад; купила четыре фарфоровые чашки; на изгороди из трех жердей сидели три женские фигуры (А.Н. Толстой); По этим дорогам двигаются две большие колонны немцев (М. Бубеннов).
3. Если формы именительного падежа множественного числа существительных женского рода **отличаются по ударению** от формы родительного падежа единственного числа (ср.: го́ры – горы́, слёзы – слезы́), то определение в рассматриваемой конструкции обычно ставится в родительном падеже множественного числа: две высоких горы, две крупных слезы. Например: Три серых струны натянулись в воздухе (Горький); Две сильных мужских руки подхватили ее (А. Коптяева).

**Пояснение**

1. Современный вариант: ***два самых маленьких дисканта***.

Дело не в роде, а **в общем правиле** для количественных оборотов. Их **современная грамматика** такова.  Два (чего?) дисканта, управление Р.п.,  числительное — главное слово. Дисканта (каких?) маленьких, согласование в Р.п.; существительное — главное слово.

2. **Исключение**  делается для существительных ж.р.: две маленькие темы.
   Определение «маленькие»  согласуется с числительным «две» **в форме И.п.**, если форма Р.п. «нет тЕмы» в точности до ударения **повторяет** форму мн. числа «многие тЕмы».

В этом случае применяется **другая грамматическая схема**, привычная для слуха: две (чего?) темы, две (какие?) маленькие. Прилагательное согласуется с **числительным** «две»  **НЕПОСРЕДСТВЕННО** в форме И.п., в то время как правильным является согласование прилагательного **с существительным** «темы» в форме Р.п.

Рекомендуется:  Две  маленьких странЫ, если формы **не совпадают** по ударению.

3. Раньше схема согласования **по И.п.** применялась для  существительных **всех родов,** в то же время  согласование по Р.п. **также существовало.** (Это опять тема текстологии.) Однако время показало  **некорректность и условность** такой грамматической формы. В настоящий момент она применяется только для существительных **женского рода**, да и то при совпадении разных форм для существительного.
4. **Почему же так произошло?** Казалось бы, что может быть естественнее, чем согласование **рядом стоящих** слов? Именно так правильно! Но числительное **не образует** словосочетания непосредственно с прилагательным, и постепенно это становилось очевидным.Так **правильное** на поверку оказалось  **неправильным**.

Comment: Да, но почему это существовало/существует только для числительных два, три, четыре? Вот еще окончание же меняется после 4. Одна - кожа, две - кожи, три - кожи, четыре - кожи, пять - кож.

Comment: Один –  это счетно-местоименное слово, но не грамматическое числительное. Там только согласование, нет управления.  Управление существует для И.п. и В.п. , а в остальных падежах заменяется согласованием.  Это основной закон числительных как класса слов/ частей речи. Но именно в этих падежах два, три, четыре используются в форме ед. числа (исключение). Два дерева – двумя деревьями (согласование в Т.п. мн.числа, исключения кончились).  Как вам такая грамматика))

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon! В конце разве "на проверку", не "на поверку"?))

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. Я исправлю (вроде бы так принято говорить в подобных случаях).

Answer (score 2):

*А два самые маленькие дисканта...*
Да, Артем, именно **так** обычно писали до первой трети двадцатого века (не так, как сейчас — *два сам**ых** маленьк**их** дисканта*).

*Борька с издевательской насмешкой доказывал, что из культурных способов отвлечения людей от серьезных умственных запросов **два самые верные и незаметные** — футбол и шахматы* (В. В. Вересаев. Исанка (**1928**)).

*Старичок слушал, сидя странно прямо и неподвижно, за стеклами его очков мать видела **два маленькие бесцветные пятнышка*** (Максим Горький. Мать (**1906**)).

***Два самые общеупотребительные источника** в Эмсе, несмотря на несколько других, — это Кренхен и Кессельбрунен* (Ф. М. Достоевский. Дневник писателя. 1876 год (**1876**)).

*Первыми друзьями молодого вдовства княгини были **два самые скромные лица**, имена которых я уже упоминала...* (Н. С. Лесков. Захудалый род (**1874**)).

Информация для подтверждения:
[два самые...](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqIQoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAKNysvNep9u8CQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHQtNCy0LAg0YHQsNC80YvQtTAB) (Нацкорпус);
[два маленькие...](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClIqIQoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAKLrM4I2TnfgKQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJgokCiIKA3JlcRIbChnQtNCy0LAg0LzQsNC70LXQvdGM0LrQuNC1MAE=) (Нацкорпус);
[Числительное с прилагательным в "Дневнике писателя"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452240/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/463448#463448) (похожий вопрос).

Comment: По-разному писали, все зависит от того, как понимать грамматику. В конце концов грамматическая модель с Р.п. стала основной. А. П. Чехов. Именины (1888)  На аллее показались два маленьких гимназиста, дети помещицы Чижевской, только что приехавшие, а с ними студент-гувернер в белом кителе и в очень узких брюках. Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Три конца (1890) 
Два маленьких оконца едва освещали эту галдевшую толпу; в воздухе висел табачный дым, и делалось жарко, как в бане.

Comment: Конечно же, по-разному писали, но ошибкой (на то время) это назвать нельзя. *Это не камни – это два странные таинственные огня* (А. Куприн). *На охоте за бекасами были со мной два странные случая* (С. Аксаков). *Слушайте же: едут два веселые молодые человека* (Л. Толстой). "Конец концов" окончательно победил в двадцатом веке (к первой трети, и то не у всех).

Comment: А почему же потом перешли к Р.п.? Я думаю, что в правилах была закреплена частотная форма.  Два маленькие пятнышка... Несогласованность ведь явная, от нее постепенно ушли.

Comment: Ничего подобного. Смотрите внимательней: (https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqIQoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAKNysvNep9u8CQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHQtNCy0LAg0YHQsNC80YvQtTAB) и (https://fantlab.ru/work281434).

Comment: Еще раз: *смотрите внимательней* внимательный вы наш: название — "Дневник писателя. 1876 год", дата публикации — тоже 1876 год (а мог быть опубликован позднее). Например: "Дневник писателя. 1877 г." (впервые опубликовано отдельными выпусками в 1877 г., затем отдельным изданием (СПб., 1878)).

Comment: Спасибо большое, Рим!

Answer (score 2):

> Раньше так было правильно и для мужского рода?

Да, правильно.

**Из книги Василия Ильича Чернышева «Правильность и чистота русской речи», изданной в начале 20-го века:**

> Имена прилагательные, причастия и одинаково склоняющиеся с ними
> числительные и местоимения, будучи поставлены при существительных,
> зависящих от числительных *два (две), три, четыре, оба,* принимают
> форму именительного или родительного падежа множественного числа.
> Допуская обороты: два ***молодые*** человека и два ***молодых***
> человека – **авторы отдают на практике заметное предпочтение первому
> из них.** Преобладание именительного мы можем указать у Пушкина,
> Лермонтова, Гоголя, Тургенева, Гончарова, Достоевского, Салтыкова, Л.
> Толстого и др.
>
> Два голубя как два ***родные*** брата жили. Крылов, Два голубя. <…>

Comment: Спасибо большое, Слав!